# Error: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0. How can I resolve?

Tags: android, cursor

This is my code:

```
package com.dev.paolo.sicinf;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.math.BigInteger;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;


public class KeySettings extends ActionBarActivity {

    public void generateKey(View view)
    {
        Intent RSA = new Intent (this, RSA.class);
        startActivity(RSA);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_key_settings);
        ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_keys);
        List list = new LinkedList();
        ManagerDB db = new ManagerDB(this);
        Cursor c= null;
        String textD,textE,textN;
        BigInteger d,e,N;
        try {
            db.open();
        } catch (SQLException a) {
            a.printStackTrace();
        }
        try
        {
            c = db.getKey(0);
        }
        catch (SQLException a)
        {
            a.printStackTrace();
        }
        textD = c.getString(2);
        d = new BigInteger(textD);
        try
        {
            c = db.getKey(1);
        }
        catch (SQLException a) {
            a.printStackTrace();
        }
        textE = c.getString(2);
        e = new BigInteger(textE);
        try
        {
            c = db.getKey(2);
        } catch (SQLException a)
        {
            a.printStackTrace();
        }
        textN = c.getString(2);
        N = new BigInteger(textN);
        db.close();
        list.add(new Key("Public Key",e + " , " + N));
        list.add(new Key("Private Key",d + " , " + N));
        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,R.layout.rowcustom,list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

and this is the error reported:

```
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2365)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1258)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5350)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
```

I don't know how to resolve this problem. I've tried many guides available online but I haven't found a solution.

Comment: error is in which method/line

Comment: Your cursor is empty.

Comment: Der Golem could you tell me how can I resolve?

Answer (score 0):

This error is occurring because `db.getKey()` is trying to access the first item in an empty list (I'm guessing a list of keys in this case). You need to either add something to the database before you get to this point or add some handling for an empty database.

Comment: about "add some handling for an empty database", how can I do this? if you can tell me the exact code to write, It would be nicer.

Comment: If you have access to the `db.keys` list (assuming that's what its called, I have never used ManagerDB) then add a check `if(db.keys.size > 0)` otherwise add `CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException` to the catch block of your try/catch statements and handle the error in there

Comment: sorry, but I can't understand. Could you write me exactly how I should change my code?